# How to add sqlite3 dependency to VS Code extension?

Tags: sqlite, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to make extension in Typescript for VS Code using sqlite3 library.

I have project.json like this:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.42",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.43",
    "@types/sqlite3": "^3.1.3",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "vscode": "^1.1.6"
}
```

after installing dependency Typescript can import sqlite3 happily (intellisense does not mind) but after running extension I will get following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\projekty\MyFirstCodeExt\sqlite-starter\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v54-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

I guess it is related to electron rebuild but I cannot figure how to proceed.

UPDATE:
I checked the path:

> \node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v54-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

but found instead:

> \node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Do you used npm install or yarn?

Comment: I have tried both. Not working. But I know where is error. See update above

Comment: Looks like Electron and your Node use different ABI versions, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with other versions (v64 & v69). I resolved it by switching to [better-sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3) and using [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild).

Also few links with similar problems:

- https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/906
- https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1199

On Windows:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd -v 6.1.2
```

6.1.2 is the electron version can be checked in Help -> About